# mongoDB laravel search query taking too much time

Tags: laravel, mongodb

i have 400000+ records now stored in MongoDB with a regular indexed but when i fire a update or search query through laravel elenquote it's taking too much time to get the particular records.
in where condition we have use indexed columns only.

we are using atlas M10 cluster instance with multiple replicas
so anyone have a some idea about it please share us

my replication lag graph
[image]

this is my profiler data

[image]

My Indexs in schema

[image]

Comment: short answer is it depends. the slow query can be caused by: 1) improper indexing on the data - too few is bad, too much is worse; 2) the query itself; 3) connection between replicas - yes, some bandwith lag may cause problem. that being said, your first thing to do is to profile your query, see how the query is made and check if its efficient enough (some orm might glitch on some edge cases and causes problem).

Comment: thank you @BagusTesa i have update my lag graph in my question please check over there

Comment: I think your indexes have low selectivity and need to be reviewed. Because keys examined and docs returned is half the size of the collection. Could you please share collection schema, indexes and query with us

Comment: @PavelBely Thanks, i have added my indexes image over there please look at this. and for query i have using eloquent query of laravel in this i m using select title from job where feed_id ='id'

Comment: @RajatAhuja thanks, how unique is feed_id? Also try running explain for that mentioned query in mongo shell - it'll show you what index is utilized and more

Comment: @PavelBely in this collection feed_id is not unique it's indexed because of we are using this on where condition that's why we indexed this column. i have tried this query in mongo shell it's working fine but in my application it's taking time and entered in slowest query