# How to speed up MongoDB update and search query with Laravel?

Tags: php, database, mongodb, eloquent, nosql

I am working on setting up my project with MongoDB with Laravel. However things are smooth till now but I am stuck at a point.
I have approx. 400 000 records stored in MongoDB with regular indexing onto them.

Now as I try to run an update or search query for 100 000 - 150 000 records through Laravel Eloquent it's taking around 6 seconds only to get the records and  for `UPDATE` single record its taking approx. 10 seconds  with `WHERE` condition.

As I am using indexed columns only for my query I believe that the time its taking is way too high if considered with MongoDB.
Also to mention I am using ATLAS M10 Cluster instance with Multiple Replicas.

Am I missing on something to make this operation more quicker?

Comment: Highly similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492670/mongodb-laravel-search-query-taking-too-much-time), is that your alt account or a colleague? (Don't double post)

Comment: Thanks for your consideration @brombeer . Can I get some insight over it?

Comment: narrowing down on the cause for a slow query is a complicated task. you will need "on site" profilling and optimizing queries. its not limited to laravel only, its a gruesome stuff.

Comment: I think you should take a look at MongoDB Atlas Search for any search use cases.

Comment: People living outside India don't use words like 'lac' or 'lakh' -- so please don't use Indian words like that here. People aren't going to understand you.